# SQL Server Rules of Precedence

Tags: sql-server-2008

What is the difference between two queries :

Query #1:

```
select * 
from Employee 
where Job_id = 'SA_REP' OR Job_id = 'AD_PRES' AND salary > 15000
```

Output:

```
EmpId   Last_name   Job_ID  Salary
1   King    AD_PRES 24000
2   Abel    SA_REP  11000
3   Taylor  SA_REP  8600
4   Grant   SA_REP  7000
```

Query #2:

```
select * 
from Employee 
where (Job_id = 'SA_REP' OR Job_id = 'AD_PRES') AND salary > 15000
```

Output:

```
EmpId   Last_name   Job_ID  Salary
1   King    AD_PRES 24000
```

Comment: One difference is that the second one has an order of operations that is clear without having to lookup if AND and OR have the same precedence or not.

Comment: From your own experiment you can see that the first one is equivalent to `Job_id = 'SA_REP' OR (Job_id = 'AD_PRES' AND salary > 15000)` Also, operator precedence can be easily researched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first query you will get all Employees with a Job_ID of 'SA-REP' no matter what their salary is and Employees with a Job_ID of 'AD_PRES' and salary > 15000. In the second query you will get Employees whose salary > 15000 and also have a Job_ID of 'SA_REP' or 'AD_PRES'.